# How do I add gesture to AVPlayerController's subtitles?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

plz help me to solve problem.. I can't find any question about this..

I'm going to add Subtitle in AVPlayerViewController.

I did it. But, My customer wanted to add gesture to subtitles.

for Instance,

1. click subtitle's some keyword
2. pass the "clicked keyword" to another Controller
3. just present anotherController with clikced keyword.

first... is it possible to add gesture to subtitles?

I didn't have lots of experience about coding...

I'm not very well in English.. sry..TT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

안녕 Woo sung Kim! Welcome to the forum. Unfortunately, the short answer is **no**. There is no api to query the word at a specific tap location and the content isn't even rendered using a `UILabel` (or `CATextLayer`).

The longer answer is: If you reeeeeally want to do it there are options but I wouldn't use this for production. Checking out the view hierarchy of an `AVPlayerViewController` while displaying subtitles will show you that the subtitles are rendered within an `FigFCRCALayerOutputNodeLayer`. On a simulator running iOS 14.4 this layer is at
`avPlayerVc.view.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.layer.sublayers?.first?.sublayers?[1].sublayers?.first?.sublayers?.first?.sublayers?.first` (this could change anytime in the future and probably doesn't even work below this version). The text is directly set as the layers `content` (including the rounded semi-transparent background view).

[image]

I played around with Vision for a bit and while it lags a little it somewhat works to feed the layers content (CGImage) to a text recognition request and then split the result into words and checking whether the touch location is within the bound of the words. To get the touch point I subclassed `AVPlayerViewController` (I know, it's bad, but if you use an `AVPlayerLayer` directly it's even easier) and converted the touch from `touchesBegan` to screen coordinates:

```
final class PlayerVC: AVPlayerViewController {
  var onTap: ((CGPoint) -> Void)?

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

    guard let tapLocation = touches.first?.location(in: nil) else { return }
    onTap?(tapLocation)
  }
}
```

The actual code to get a word at the location looks like this (`playerVc` points to a `PlayerVC` instance:

```
func tap(tapLocation: CGPoint) {
    guard
        let subtitleLayer = playerVc.view.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.layer.sublayers?.first?.sublayers?[1].sublayers?.first?.sublayers?.first?.sublayers?.first,
        CFGetTypeID(subtitleLayer.contents as CFTypeRef) == CGImage.typeID
    else { return }

    let image = subtitleLayer.contents as! CGImage
    let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: image)
    let recognizeTextHandler: (VNRequest, Error?) -> Void = { request, error in
        guard let observations = request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation] else { return }

        for observation in observations {
            guard let topCandidate = observation.topCandidates(1).first, topCandidate.string != "" else { continue }

            for word in topCandidate.string.components(separatedBy: " ") {
                guard let range = topCandidate.string.range(of: word) else { continue }

                if let boundinBox = try? topCandidate.boundingBox(for: range) {

                    let transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                        .scaledBy(x: 1, y: -1)
                        .translatedBy(x: 0, y: -subtitleLayer.frame.size.height)
                        .scaledBy(x: subtitleLayer.frame.size.width, y: subtitleLayer.frame.size.height)

                    let convertedTopLeft = boundinBox.topLeft.applying(transform)
                    let convertedBottomRight = boundinBox.bottomRight.applying(transform)

                    let localRect = CGRect(x: convertedTopLeft.x,
                                                                 y: convertedTopLeft.y,
                                                                 width: convertedBottomRight.x - convertedTopLeft.x,
                                                                 height: convertedBottomRight.y - convertedTopLeft.y)

                    let globalRect = subtitleLayer.convert(localRect, to: nil)

                    if globalRect.contains(tapLocation) {
                        print("You tapped \(word)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    let request = VNRecognizeTextRequest(completionHandler: recognizeTextHandler)
    request.usesLanguageCorrection = false
    request.recognitionLevel = .accurate

    do {
        try requestHandler.perform([request])
    } catch {
        print("Unable to perform the request \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. my SSABOO(master) in Lan!!
Thank you for your kindness.
I understand well. What you've added to the code and the photographs...
really really thank you. 
It feels like this. I feel like I've seen the light in a cave!!
Good Luck all day!!